# ipython post-mortem debugging: scope of outer function

Tags: python, ipython, pdb, ipdb

Consider the following code:

```
def inner(a):
    if a == 75:
        raise RuntimeError()
    return a**2

def outer():
    results = []
    for a in range(100):
        results.append(inner(a))
    return results

outer()
```

In IPython, after the exception was raised, the `%debug` line magic opens the python debugger at the scope of `inner()`:

```
In [4]: %debug
> <ipython-input-3-eff43b15b2ef>(3)inner()
      2     if a == 75:
----> 3         raise RuntimeError()
      4     return a**2

ipdb> a
a = 75
ipdb> results
*** NameError: name 'results' is not defined
```

How can you tell (i)pdb to enter the scope of `outer()` in order to save the results generated so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can directly do it. However, once inside the debugger, you can easily type `u` (for up) to move the current frame one level up and be inside the `outer` function. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) for more informations on the commands.